# How do I terminate a multithreaded program due to a fatal error in one of the threads without getting "Pure virtual called" errors?

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++, console-application, runtime-error

I have a console application which launches multiple worker threads with little synchronization needed. If one of the threads has an exception, I'm using `boost::copy_exception` to return it to the main thread. But when I exit the application in the main thread (either with `boost::rethrow_exception` or with `exit(1)`) after detecting the worker thread error, I get `"pure virtual function called."`

It seems that the other worker threads are still running at various points and some of the objects they depend on get (partially?) destroyed by the main thread before the worker threads get terminated. I'm kind of guessing there because naturally it doesn't happen when I attach the debugger.

How can I kill all the threads simultaneously to avoid this, preferably without adding a huge number of interruption points? Or maybe I'm misinterpreting the error entirely...

I'm using MSVC 9 on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: The traditional way to do this would be for the main thread to tell all of the child threads that they need to exit now, and then have the main thread wait for them to exit (by calling pthread_join() or whatever the boost equivalent of that is, for each child thread) before exiting itself.  That way you avoid the possibility of the child threads accessing global resources after the main thread has deallocated them, which is likely what is causing the errors you see.

Comment: It would help if the main thead stopped deallocating stuff that it does not need to!

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: Is that possible without the huge number of interruption points that I mentioned? Does the runtime start to free global variables when the main thread exits without waiting for other threads to exit?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner - the traditional way is not always appropriate, (in fact, it hardly ever is).  In this case, I seems like something specific to copy_exception().

Comment: What happens if you call _exit(1) instead of exit(1)?

Comment: @MartinJames: That appears to correctly exit all threads at the same time. I don't get the runtime error. Why?

Comment: I'm not sure.  exit() does a full C++ runtime 'cleanup', _exit() does not.  It seems a reasonable guess that the full cleanup fails, throws and refuses to continue, leaving the main thread unable to continue on and reach its ExitProcess() API.  Not cleaning up is much cleaner - the main thread reaches the ExitProcess() call without throwing and the OS then blows away all your threads.  The downside is that file buffers are not flushed, DB connections not closed, that sort of thing.  The upside is that you don't have any thread-termination hassle - the OS can kill all your threads no problem.

Comment: Another factor is that exit() probably calls dtors for static objects.  If there are threads accessing them after destruction there may be 'issues'.

Comment: We have a lot of static singletons so that could very well be it. So, in general, I want to be able to do this in a clean way (I might not want to always exit the process). So I guess putting interruption points in the worker thread loops is going to be necessary.